# Can we just use Rolle's theorem to prove Taylor's Theorem, or is there another way?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The following real function, $h(x)$, is twice differentiable and $a$, $b$ are distinct real numbers: 
$$h(x)=f(b)-f(x)-(b-x)f'(x)+\frac{K(b-x)^2}{2}$$
where the constant $K$ is chosen so that $h(a)=0$.

Show that there is a real number $c$ lying between $a$ and $b$ such that
$$f(b)=f(a)+(b-a)f'(a)+\frac{(b-a)^2}{2}f''(c)$$

Additionally if $f''(x)\ge0$ show that we have $f(a+h)-f(a)>f(a)-f(a-h)$.

Comment: Where did you find this problem ?

Comment: Part of a problem set.  Is any clarification needed?

Comment: Read Lax et al _Calculus with Applications and Computing vol. 1_ (1976) pp. 134-143.